# How to solve the issue with beacon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, beacon

My Problem: When I click the button, my phone will show a progress view(ask me come close the beacon), and when I come close the beacon, my phone will show a view(checkmark), and then remove the view 1.5s later. Now the view can show normally first, but when I take my phone far away from the beacon, and the view(show checkmark) will show 1s later. It's a big problem out of my mind.
My code:

**onClick button**

```
- (IBAction)chooseBLEAction:(id)sender {
    self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    [self _initBeaconRegion];

    if (([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse ||
         [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
         [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) &&
        [self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
    {
        [self _start];

        if (self.bluetoothIsOpen) {
            [self _createProgressView];
        }
    }else {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
}

- (void)_start {
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.targetBeaconRegion];
}

- (void)_stop {
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.targetBeaconRegion];
}
```

**CLLocationManagerDelegate**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray<CLBeacon *> *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"searching for beacon ！");

    CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [CLBeacon new];
    foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];
    if (foundBeacon) {
        NSLog(@"found beacon ！");

        switch (foundBeacon.proximity) {
            case CLProximityUnknown:
                break;

            case CLProximityFar:
                break;

            case CLProximityNear:
                break;

            case CLProximityImmediate:
            {
                [self _stop];
                NSLog(@"Immediate beacon ！");
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1051);

                [self.myProgressView removeFromSuperview];
                [self _createSuceessProgressView];

                self.removeProgressViewTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self selector:@selector(_removeSuccessProgressView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**create progress view (close the beacon)**

```
- (void)_createProgressView {
    NSString *title = @"Please close the beacon";
    self.myProgressView = [MRProgressOverlayView showOverlayAddedTo:self.view title:title mode:MRProgressOverlayViewModeIndeterminate animated:YES];
}
```

**create success view**

```
- (void)_createSuceessProgressView {
    NSString *title = @"Success!";
    self.suceessProgressView = [MRProgressOverlayView showOverlayAddedTo:self.view title:title mode:MRProgressOverlayViewModeCheckmark animated:YES];
}
```

**remove success view 1.5s later**

```
- (void)_removeSuccessProgressView {
    [self.removeProgressViewTimer invalidate];
    [self.suceessProgressView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Explain what you want to do. You want to show a progress view when the beacon comes close, and then remove the progress view as the user moves away? Then explain how your code is supposed to accomplish that goal and the problem you're having. (I don't see any code for removing the progress view when the user moves away from the beacon.)

Comment: Oh yeah. And "slove" is not a word. Did you mean "solve"? Even then, it isn't clear what you mean. An iBeacon is a tool. You don't "solve" a tool, you *use* a tool to accomplish a task.